# Play Akka logger doesn't output debug messages to console

Tags: scala, logging, playframework-2.0, akka, slf4j

I'm trying to setup debug logging to console from Akka actors with Scala `2.11.6` and Play `2.4.6`. So I see info messages with this config, but not debug:

application.conf:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  level = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

logback.xml:

```
<logger name="akka" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="actors" level="DEBUG" />
```

usage:

```
package actors

import akka.actor._
import akka.event.Logging

object DispatchActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new DispatchActor(out))
}

class DispatchActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  log.debug("akka started: info")


  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      log.debug("actor received a message")
      out ! ("I received your message: " + msg)
  }

  override def postStop() = {
    log.info("actor closed")
  }
}
```

I see debug messages from the app (thrown in controller, for example), but not from actors. Starting app like `activator debug run`

Answer (score 4):

In application.conf, try changing to:

```
akka {
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

You have "level" instead of "loglevel". That fixed this for me.